# Is there a way to enable / disable constraints in db2 v7?

Tags: database, db2, constraints

I have to copy tables from an Oracle database to a db2 v7 one, and in order to do this (avoiding millions of drops and creates) I'd like to know if db2 has a feature like Oracle to enable / disable constraints temporarily without dropping them.

Thanks in advance,
Mauro.

Answer (score 6):

You can do:

```
ALTER TABLE <table-name> ALTER FOREIGN KEY <constraint-name> NOT ENFORCED
```

and then to re-enable:

```
ALTER TABLE <table-name> ALTER FOREIGN KEY <constraint-name> ENFORCED
```

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/mptoolic/v1r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2tools.ama.doc.ug/amacric0.htm

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this works in version 7, but you can try the following:

```
set integrity for table_name off
set integrity for table_name foreign key immediate unchecked
```

And then you can do your inserts.  To re-enable, you can then do the following:

```
set integrity for table_name immediate checked
```

Comment: This actually doesn't disable the constraints. The first line disables them, but puts the table in the "check pending state" which basically means you cannot perform most operations on it. The second line enables the constraints again, so it does the same thing as the third line. The only difference is in the word checked/unchecked, which means if the constrains should be checked for violations right after turning them back on.